# Best Solution for Real Time Complex Queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, real-time

So I've been building an analytics tool in crypto that requires ingesting a few billion rows of data across a couple tables. Sales, Listings, NFTs, Metadata, Contract info, etc. I take that data and machine learn on it, outputting quite a bit of data for every contract every hour into another table. The data is extremely relational and the end result is trying to output large aggregates of data based on complex queries with many joins (think taking every asset in the 500 projects with the most sales in the last 3 days, joining to their metadata attributes, joining those attributes to their most recent mle results, and then slicing that data 20 different ways).

I currently have an 8 vCPU Postgresql RDS with 32 GB RAM and with 5-6 materialized views on it, it runs at 75%+ average CPU util and takes 10-15 mins+ to update some of the views, so anything that then queries those views takes an eternity to respond basically half of the time. I've looked into cube, timescale, redshift, etc. The stream based dbs seem quite difficult to set up highly related historical data with and the relational database don't have the concept of incrementally updated materialized views yet.

What should I do? I'd be willing to pay up to $1000/mo to solve the problem in a scalable way (maybe 10-100 billion rows across a few tables that can query from views that don't hold up reads and writes) Hopefully I can up that number soon but for now I'm fronting all the costs with no income from this yet

Comment: Please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, COSTS) for the queries involved, and also the DDL for the tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look hard at Redshift.  It's columnar and designed for large analytic queries. It's SQL is based on postgres so the port effort could be manageable.    Some aspect of your current solution may not fit well on Redshift but it should be able to hit the cost and analytic performance goals you are stating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process data in real-time you should try publishing your data into a technology designed for the job. Something like Confluent Kafka.

Once the data is being streamed to your message broker you can then process and handle the data in any way you choose. You can have multiple small services for each of your business needs. You will probably have to write data to a database in the end, but this will likely be a much smaller volume contain only the results you really need to store.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately PostGresql does not have technics ans functionnalities to help to have good performances about your problems.

- PostGreSQL does not have **"In Memory" tables** (that reduce contention by having no access to data disks nor transaction log)
- PostGreSQL does not have **native C compiled stored procedure** (that accelerate execution of complex logic)
- PostGreSQL does not have **"Columnar" indexes** (that reduce index size and acces for big tables)
- PostGreSQL is very limited to **parallelize queries** (only 4 operations supports multi threading and you have to do it manualy...)
- PostGreSQL does not have **data compression** for tables or indexes (that reduce access time without the need to decompress to access to the data)
- PostGreSQL does not have **Indexed View** (that are always synchronized to source data and does not need any refresh)
- PostGreSQL does not have a **"batch" processing mode** to access data globally by "block" instead of rows into indexes
- and finally PostGreSQL does not have a **specialized data engine for analytics** that automatically process cubes for BI

But thoses technics and functionnalities exists in some other RDBMS like Microsoft SQL Server (auto parallelization of "heavy" queries, ColumStore Indexes, In Memory table, native procedure, indexed views, compression, batch processing mode, SSAS engine for BI...)

Of course you need to pay a licence for all this stuff, but you will have to pay much more to have a super computer for PostGreSQL without having the same performances.

As an example, I have done some performances tests on some very simple queries that demontsrates how slow is PostGreSQL in front of SQL Server :

[PostGreSQL vs Microsoft SQL Server – Comparison part 2 : COUNT performances](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/)
This paper demonstrate that PostGreSQL is on average 90 times slower that SQL Server and in the worst case (with columnstore indexes) 1500 time slower...

[PostGreSQL vs Microsoft SQL Server – Comparison part 1 : DBA command performances](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-part-1-dba-queries-performances/)
This paper demonstrate that PostGreSQL is about 20 time sower in basic DBA operations

Ask you why StackOverflow runs on Microsoft SQL Server and not on PostGreSQL ?

Comment: Adyen is running PostgreSQL, handling 100’s of TB of data and has a market capitalization of 46.7 billion euro. Why? Because they are familiar with it. Just like the guys behind Stackoverflow are familiar with SQL Server

Comment: In real life you have to know how to be pragmatic and adapt. If the need is such that PostGreSQL is not the solution, then you have to change. **Errare humanum est, perseverare diabolicum...**

Comment: And as usual, PG is unnable to have 50 Tb in one database. As Adyen Says, *"Our database setup at Adyen is unique for a few reasons. We currently process 5,000+ PostgreSQL transactions per second across **multiple clusters**.* Personnaly I have at home about 47 Tb of data in 5 SQL Server Instances. But one of my customer have 42 Tb in only one database. This make a great difference ! (https://www.adyen.com/blog/updating-a-50-terabyte-postgresql-database)

Comment: And they are still worth over 46 billion euro… at least 46 billion euro more than our combined net worth. The two of us must be doing something wrong

Comment: Lots of companies have a lot of money but that has nothing to do with choosing an RDBMS. I also wonder why you take out this argument which seems silly to me!

Comment: In France, a small country, we have several large companies (10 to 40 Billion euros) which exclusively use SQL Server and are doing very well, such as Bouyghes, L'Oréal or Géodis... But that still doesn't mean anything about the choice of RDBMS!

Comment: In switzerland, Migro (about 30 billions €) use exclusively MS SQL Server... Did that mean anything ?

Comment: Than why do you complain about a database when it doesn’t matter and still gets the job done?